# emacs call-interactively and key simulation

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to write a small function that saves the cursor's current position, mark the whole buffer, indents it and then goes back to the previous cursor position. I understand there might be easier way to achieve the same result but I'd like to understand how these principles work in Elisp.

Here's what I tried to do :

```
(defun indent-whole-buffer () (interactive)                                                                                                                                                                        
    (call-interactively 'point-to-register)                                                                                                                                                                    
    (call-interactively (kbd "RET"))                                                                                                                                                                                 
    (mark-whole-buffer)                                                                                                                                                                                              
    (call-interactively 'indent-region)                                                                                                                                                                              
    (call-interactively 'jump-to-register)                                                                                                                                                                           
    (call-interactively (kbd "RET"))                                                                                                                                                                                 
  )
```

The blocking point here is  the `(call-interactively (kbd "RET"))` how can I simulate the RET key, just as if I was doing

```
M-x point-to-register RET
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `save-excursion`. That's what it's for.  It saves point and mark and which buffer is current, and then restores them for you.

(And if you did decide to roll your own, and you did decide to do it in the way you planned, then just call the functions you need directly - no need to use `call-interactively`. Use `C-h f` to see how each function is called. For example `(point-to-register ?a)` captures `point` in register `a`, and `(indent-region (point-min) (point-max))` indents the whole buffer.)

Comment: Well, in my head, when I write `(call-interactively 'point-to-register)`, it does `M-x point-to-register` and I would like to send "RET" automatically to specify an empty register.

Comment: `C-x r SPC RET` (or `M-x point-to-register RET`) raises an error `Non-character input-event`, because you did not provide a register name. Interactively of non-interactively, you must pass a register (which is a character) to function `point-to-register`. `C-h f point-to-register` tells you the calling sequence, where you can see that parameter `REGISTER` is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs Lisp is not just the macro language used by Emacs — it's the implementation language.  Many Emacs functions have more functionality than what is exposed through the UI, and it is often possible to write more compact and elegant code by using this functionality.

In particular, if your goal is to indent the whole buffer, then there is no need to move point and mark around — the function `indent-region` is able to indent an arbitrary region:

```
(defun indent-whole-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (indent-region (point-min) (point-max)))
```